# 5 times Duplicate data in sub report in Details section in Crystal Report

Tags: c++, crystal-reports

Please help me ! I have a problem in Crystal Report at visual studio:

I have 2 sub reports within the main report , and I put them at report header section it is fine, when i run the report , the sub reports duplicated 5 times ..

My wrong output

Name EmpId  Status  Destination  CallType

a     011     Y       US           ISD

a     011     Y       US           ISD

a     011     Y       US           ISD

a     011     Y       US           ISD

a     011     Y       US           ISD

a     012     Y       US           STD

a     012     Y       US           STD

a     012     Y       US           STD

a     012     Y       US           STD

a     012     Y       US           STD

a     011     N       UK           ISD

a     011     N       UK           ISD

a     011     N       UK           ISD

a     011     N       UK           ISD

a     011     N       UK           ISD

My Correctoutput

Name EmpId  Status  Destination  CallType

a     011     Y       US           ISD

a     012     Y       US           STD

a     011     N       UK           ISD

thanks for solution .

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be the linking of tables in database....

try checking the option `select distinct records` in `database tab`.

```
Database ---> Select distinct records
```

Also I would suggest you to check the linking once.

Comment: How should i link? and how to select distinct records? Here I linked by name in which CallType of Table1 is linked to CallType of Table2

Comment: Already explaing check my answer for checking distinct records. May be your linking is producing duplicate records.... you need to explain more on what you have done in report

Comment: You can check your links by
Right Clicking Database Fields -> Database Expert --> Links. You can add/remove links there.

Also when you run the report, if possible try SQL profiling it to see what JOINS are being used no the table.